# Error using facebook C# sdk with WPF web browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am new to facebook c# sdk. I followed the tutorial in [this link](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx).

I created an application that displays the user name after log in. Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string appId = "appid";
    private string extenededPermissions = "offline_access,publish_stream";
    private Uri loginUrl = null;
    private string accessToken = null;
    private string userName = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to get the login url
    /// with the requested permissions
    /// </summary>
    private void GetLoginUrl()
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        // add the client id
        parameters.client_id = appId;
        // add the redirect uri
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        // requested response
        parameters.response_type = "token";
        // type of display
        parameters.display = "popup";
        // If extended permissions are present
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extenededPermissions))
            parameters.scope = extenededPermissions;
        // Create the login url
        Facebook fc = new FacebookClient();
        loginUrl = fc.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }

    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the login url
        GetLoginUrl();
        // Navigate to that page
        webBrowser.Navigate(loginUrl);
    }

    private void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var fc = new FacebookClient();
        FacebookOAuthResult fr;
        // Check the returned url
        if (fc.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out fr))
        {
            // check if authentication is success or not
            if (fr.IsSuccess)
            {
                getUserName(out userName);
            }
            else
            {
                var errorDes = fr.ErrorDescription;
                var errorReason = fr.ErrorReason;
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    private void getUserName(out string name)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        // Get the user details
        dynamic result = fb.Get("me");
        // Get the user name
        name = result.name;
        MessageBox.Show("Hai " + name + ",Welcome to my App");
    }

}
```

My Problem is with the `FacebookOAuthResult`.

```
    private void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var fc = new FacebookClient();
        FacebookOAuthResult fr;
        // Check the returned url
        if (fc.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out fr))
        {
            // check if authentication is success or not
            if (fr.IsSuccess)
            {
                getUserName(out userName);
            }
            else
            {
                var errorDes = fr.ErrorDescription;
                var errorReason = fr.ErrorReason;
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

After I logged in it is redirecting to `redirect_uri`. But the `fc.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out fr)` fails though the webbrowser redirects to the Authentication successful page.

So I couldn't get the access token. What could the problem in my code be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i have found out the solution..Thanks to the answers for the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044657/facebook-username-wpf)!

I have added the **Winforms web browser control** to the wpf and the authentication is working.The problem is with **WPF web browser**. It **simply omits the url  after # token** So the parseurl won't able to authenticate it.

Here's the modified code..

```
       private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
          // create the windows form host
        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost sample = 
                       new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
        // create a new web browser
        webBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        // add it to winforms
        sample.Child = webBrowser;
        // add it to wpf
        canvas1.Children.Add(sample);

        webBrowser.Navigated += webBrowser_Navigated;
        webBrowser.Navigate(loginURL);
       }

     void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
      {
         // do the authentication
         var fc = new FacebookClient();
         FacebookOAuthResult fr;
         // Check the returned url
         if (fc.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Url, out fr))
         {
            // check if authentication is success or not
            if (fr.IsSuccess)
            {
                accessToken = fr.AccessToken;
                // Actions to do

            }
            else
            {
                var errordes = fr.ErrorDescription;
                var errorreason = fr.ErrorReason;
            }
         }
         else
         {
             //Not a valid url
         }
      }
```

The problem is solved!!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question, but I see you are asking for an offline_access permission. Facebook removed offline_access sometime ago. Instead you need an Extended Access Token. You get it by exchanging the access token you are trying to get, for an extended one. They last for about 2-3 months after which you have to get a new one.

Comment: But even after removing the offline_access,the problem still persists.